# Adobe Illustrator: Create an helix

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Can someone help me create a spiral (helix) similar to the one shown in the image? The creator (paper investigator) told me by email that uses Adobe Illustrator, but I don't know how to. Thanks!

[image: Helix]

---UPDATE---
Thanks to everybody. I need to improve it but, using the Curvature tool, this is the results:

[image]

Comment: Hola, Daniel. En el otro hilo no se llegó a ninguna solución. Gracias.

Comment: Hi Maxwell, welcome to GDSE.  Have you tried using the Pen Tool to create Bézier curves?

Comment: Hi, Billy. Yes, I'm trying with the pen tool, but like newbie i cant master it well. Thanks for the comments. I will keep on.

Comment: Maxwell, you should probably have a look at some tutorials on using the Pen Tool. Also there is a very good [online game here](http://bezier.method.ac/) for learning and practising.

Comment: If you edit the title of your question to dispute its [duplicate] status, could you also please explain why you think it's not a duplicate? Thanks! We're happy to reopen dupe questions if it turns out they aren't dupes, but we do need a good reason.

Comment: Hi, @Vincent. I'm new here and I dont know well the site yet. I think that this thread has differents points of view about the ways to create the helix, this is why I think that. But, I said, I don't know the rules yet. Thanks.

Comment: No problems, that's why I'm explaining :). If a discussion is starting about how to create the helix, I'd prefer it to be at the original question (as in: not this one), so we have all information in a single place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next isn't mathwise exact but it can be plausible enough

[image]

Start by increasing in the preferences the keyboard increment to something substantial, say 5mm instead of for ex. one pixel. Be sure you have smart guides and snap to points ON, no other snaps!

1. Draw a square
2. rotate the square 45 degrees
3. Stretch and squeeze the square to the wanted approximate plane projection size horizontally and vertically. The colored circles are the names of the corners. With the scissors tool cut the shape at the blue corner
4. With the direct selection tool select the anchors one by one and shift them with the arrow key. There's 2 anchors in the blue corner. Shift the wrong one 1 tick down. You return it later. Shift the rest anchors up:

   - green 2 ticks
   - red 4 ticks
   - orange 6 ticks
   - blue 8 ticks

Shift the starting point to its original position; one tick up.

5. With the node type conversion tool (it's under the pen) drag the nodes to smooth ones. The starting point and the ending point must have approximately identical handles
6. Make a copy. Drag it to continue the curve. If you drag its starting point when the whole curve is selected, the curve follows. It will snap. Select both curves and join them (Ctrl+J). Smooth the seam with the anchor type conversion tool.

ADD: Nearly any 3D CAD program draws it exacly right with few clicks and save it as 2D SVG or other Illustrator compatible format. This screenshot is from TurboCAD DLX trial (oops, it's CCW, but it can be mirrored)

[image]

The curve opened perfectly in Illustrator. CAD makes possible to add the terse curves, too in 3D, if one wants it. Then place the note symbols to the crossings in 2D.